# Книги по архитектуре Linux

Tags: linux, книги

Здравствуйте , вот хочу изучить как построены linux системы. То есть пользоваться умею , но хочу изучить поглубже , как что и с чем взаимодействует , как память работает , как устроены уровни защиты и так далее. Хорошо бы если было сравнение с Windows (то есть в чем принципиальная разница) . И вот хотел бы еще понять в чем разница между различными дистрибутивами linux , к примеру opensuse и debian , из чего состоит ядро системы и другое. Подскажите пожалуйста хорошие книги . 
Можно на английском , даже желательно на английском . 
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Могу порекомендовать парочку на русском (от одного из разработчиков ядра):

[Роберт Лав.  Ядро Linux. описание процесса разработки](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/17925734/)

и его же

[Linux. Системное программирование](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/26420096/)

Думаю, при желании несложно найти оригиналы.

Правда, никакого сравнения с виндоуз (а так же описания дистрибутивов) в них нет (сплошной кодинг + концепции).

Comment: Первой в продаже нет, и похоже не скоро будет, но где скачать место найдено, кому надо, гуглите.

Comment: @dsnk, [плохо искали](http://www.bgshop.ru/Details.aspx?id=10137223), конечно, цена стала совсем запредельная...